# Соединить 2 словаря поочередно

Tags: c#, сортировка, словари

Есть 2 словаря типа `Dictionary<string, Person>`, например:

```
1 словарь: 
dict1["test1"].Add(new Person{Name = "Tom", Age = "29"});            
dict1["test2"].Add(new Person{Name = "Artem", Age = "30"});
dict1["test3"].Add(new Person{Name = "Kirill", Age = "15"});

2 словарь: 
dict_2["test_8"].Add(new Person{Name = "Valeria", Age = "47"});            
dict_2["test2"].Add(new Person{Name = "Katya", Age = "20"});
dict_2["test_47"].Add(new Person{Name = "Polina", Age = "30"});
```

Мне необходимо объединить эти два словаря в один общий, чтобы значения чередовались, например:

```
3 словарь: 
dict1["test1"].Add(new Person{Name = "Tom", Age = "29"});
dict_2["test_8"].Add(new Person{Name = "Valeria", Age = "47"});            
dict1["test2"].Add(new Person{Name = "Artem", Age = "30"});
dict_2["test2"].Add(new Person{Name = "Katya", Age = "20"});
dict1["test3"].Add(new Person{Name = "Kirill", Age = "15"});       
dict_2["test_47"].Add(new Person{Name = "Polina", Age = "30"});
```

Может быть такое, что ключи будут одинаковые и в этом случае данные из второго словаря добавлялись в конец первого. 
Пробовал через функцию Zip(), но никак не получается.

Comment: _Может быть такое, что ключи будут одинаковые и в этом случае данные из второго словаря добавлялись в конец первого_  Словарь это коллекция с уникальными ключами

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. `Dictionary` - неупорядоченная коллекция и в ней могут содержаться только уникальные ключи, то я предлагаю переделать коллекции на `List<KeyValuePair>` и использовать какой-нибудь такой метод объединения:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> MyMerge<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    if (first == null) throw new ArgumentException("First argument is null");
    if (second == null) throw  new ArgumentException("Second argument is null");

    using (var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var firstMoved = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
        var secondMoved = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
        while (firstMoved && secondMoved)
        {
            yield return firstEnumerator.Current;
            yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
            firstMoved = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
            secondMoved = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        if (firstMoved)
        {
            do
            {
                yield return firstEnumerator.Current;
            } while (firstEnumerator.MoveNext());
        }
        else if (secondMoved)
        {
            do
            {
                yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
            } while (secondEnumerator.MoveNext());
        }
    }
}
```

Код расширения написан на коленке, скорее всего можно это сделать аккуратней.

Можно так, код короче, но с двойной проверкой

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> MyMerge<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    if (first == null) throw new ArgumentException("First argument is null");
    if (second == null) throw  new ArgumentException("Second argument is null");

    using (var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var firstMoved = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
        var secondMoved = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
        while (firstMoved || secondMoved)
        {
            if (firstMoved)
            {
                yield return firstEnumerator.Current;
                firstMoved = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }

            if (secondMoved)
            {
                yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
                secondMoved = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете расположить значения в словаре в каком-либо порядке, потому что порядок перечисления словаря не детерминирован.

[https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#комментарии](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.
>
> В целях перечисления каждый элемент словаря рассматривается как
>   KeyValuePair структура, представляющая значение и его
>   ключ. Порядок, в котором возвращаются элементы, не определен.